# How to understand output of GetInfeasibleConstraints()

Tags: drake

Hello in my simulation I am trying to improve my trajectory. I am trying to see what constraints are being violated. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68698187/how-to-improve-the-trajectory-optimization-results) was a good staring place.

I am printing my results like this

```py
for reason in result.GetInfeasibleConstraints(prog):
    print(f'{reason}')
    print(f'{type(reason)}')
```

which outputs this

```
PathConstraint with 24 decision variables control_point(0,0) control_point(1,0) control_point(2,0) control_point(3,0) control_point(4,0) control_point(5,0) control_point(0,1) control_point(1,1) control_point(2,1) control_point(3,1) control_point(4,1) control_point(5,1) control_point(0,2) control_point(1,2) control_point(2,2) control_point(3,2) control_point(4,2) control_point(5,2) control_point(0,3) control_point(1,3) control_point(2,3) control_point(3,3) control_point(4,3) control_point(5,3)
<class 'pydrake.solvers.BindingConstraint'>

...

PathConstraint with 24 decision variables control_point(0,0) control_point(1,0) control_point(2,0) control_point(3,0) control_point(4,0) control_point(5,0) control_point(0,1) control_point(1,1) control_point(2,1) control_point(3,1) control_point(4,1) control_point(5,1) control_point(0,2) control_point(1,2) control_point(2,2) control_point(3,2) control_point(4,2) control_point(5,2) control_point(0,3) control_point(1,3) control_point(2,3) control_point(3,3) control_point(4,3) control_point(5,3)
<class 'pydrake.solvers.BindingConstraint'>

PathConstraint with 24 decision variables control_point(0,0) control_point(1,0) control_point(2,0) control_point(3,0) control_point(4,0) control_point(5,0) control_point(0,1) control_point(1,1) control_point(2,1) control_point(3,1) control_point(4,1) control_point(5,1) control_point(0,2) control_point(1,2) control_point(2,2) control_point(3,2) control_point(4,2) control_point(5,2) control_point(0,3) control_point(1,3) control_point(2,3) control_point(3,3) control_point(4,3) control_point(5,3)
<class 'pydrake.solvers.BindingConstraint'>
```

I am having a hard time understanding what is being violated.

In my program the only constraints that contains "PathContraint" are  `AddPathPositionConstraint`, `AddPathVelocityConstraint`. But I have many other type of constraints like `PositionConstraint`, `MinimumDistanceLowerBoundConstraint`, `DistanceConstraint` etc...

I am not 100% sure which constraint is being violated. I believe am either not printing out the information correctly or I am not understanding the output correctly.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you need https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/20894 , which would make it possible for you to name the constraints as you add them, to get more interpretable output from this method.  I'll take a look at that now...

Comment: => https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/21014
I've also given default names to the bindings, so the "out of the box" messages will already be better.

Comment: That PR has landed in Drake and should now be available in the nightly release.